# How to reuse where clauses in Linq To Sql queries

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have users searching records of type Record. They type a search term in a textbox and then I search records by matching several fields with the search term.

My query looks like:

```
var results = from record in DataContext.Records
              where
                   record.Field1.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
                   record.Field2.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
                   record.Field3.ToLower().Contains(term)
              select record;
```

I have a number of queries that all use the same filter and thus I would like to extract the filtering so it can be reused. Something like:

```
var filter = new Func<Record, string, bool>(
                (record, term) =>
                    record.Field1.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
                    record.Field2.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
                    record.Field3.ToLower().Contains(term)
             );

var results = from record in DataContext.Records
              where filter(record, term)
              select record;
```

However, it does not work because:

**Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL.**

How can I reuse my where condition across queries?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a [CompiledQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.compiledquery.aspx)!

```
var filter = CompiledQuery.Compile(
    (DatabaseDataContext dc, Record record, string term) =>
        record.Field1.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
        record.Field2.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
        record.Field3.ToLower().Contains(term)
);

var results = from record in DataContext.Records
              where filter(DataContext, record, term)
              select record;
```

For more information, see [How to: Store and Reuse Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb399335.aspx).

Comment: I don't think this will work as written -- CQ.Compile produces a Func so it can't be used in the Where clause of a LINQ to SQL query.  Don't you need something like `var query = CompiledQuery.Compile((string term) => from r in DataContext.Records where r.Field1.ToLower().Contains(term) select r);` then `var results = query("someTerm");`?  Haven't used CompiledQuery so I may be wrong!

Comment: @itowlson: It does work.  This is how you create reusable functions usable in LINQ to SQL.  The query provider will recognize the compiled function and will generate the query as needed.  It doesn't just generate full queries, but it could also generate parts of queries (such as this conditional).

Comment: This works as expected. The only strange thing is that I also reuse that filter in Linq To Object queries, and then I still have to pass the Linq To Sql DataContext as a parameter. Any way to define the query independently of the DataContext?

Comment: @Xavier: The delegate generated can be used like a regular C# delegate.  It just has the added bonus to work in LINQ to SQL queries involving the data context it was compiled for.  As I understand how it works, the delegate's `Target` property is set to the associated compiled query which takes care of the query generation.  I think you might be able to compile one that would work for any data context, but you won't be able to use any LINQ to SQL classes as parameters.  Only the common types (`int`, `string`, etc.).  I'll explore this and report back.

Comment: @Xavier: On second thought, it doesn't look very plausible.  It will have very limited uses and is practically worthless.  It will only be useful when used with the data context it was compiled for.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, Jeff -- very glad to learn this trick and I will definitely be digging into it some more!

Comment: Wow, this compiled predicates trick can also be used to assemble more complex predicates and a query using them can even be compiled! It seems this makes tools like PredicateBuilder obsolete. Amazing! +10 if I could!

Answer (score 16):

You need to build an expression instead of a function:

```
Expression<Func<Record, bool>> filter = 
  record => record.Field1.ToLower().Contains(term);  // rest omitted
```

The lambda expression remains the same, but you need to return it into a variable of type `Expression<Func<Record, bool>>` -- that will make the C# compiler compile it as an expression instead of a delegate, allowing it to be passed to LINQ to SQL.

However, you won't be able to use an expression variable with a C#-syntax where clause: you'll need to use the Where extension method:

```
var results = DataContext.Records.Where(filter);
```

**Edited to add:** If you want to be able to create filters on different terms, you just need a method to produce an expression from a term:

```
private static Expression<Func<Record, bool>> Filter(string term)
{
  return r => r.Field1.ToLower().Contains(term);
}

var results = DataContext.Records.Where(Filter(term));
```

If you prefer to keep `filter` as a lambda as you have at the moment, you can do so, but the generics get a bit nested:

```
Func<string, Expression<Func<Record, bool>>> filter =
  term => (r => r.Field1.ToLower().Contains(term));

var results = DataContext.Records.Where(filter(term));
```

Regardless, the important thing is that what goes in the Where clause must be an `Expression<Func<Record, bool>>` -- but as shown above you can make the expression depend on `term` by building a suitable expression on the fly.  Which is exactly what LINQ to SQL would be doing if you spelled out the filter longhand in the Where clause.

Comment: C# syntax for the where clause is just compiler sugar; it generates the same code.

Comment: Yes, but if filter is of type Expression rather than Func, then it doesn't support the `filter(record)` syntax.  You get the error "filter is a variable but is used like a method".  And if you just write `where filter` then you get 'cannot implicitly convert type Expression(...) to bool'.

Comment: Thanks - it does make sense. However I did not manage to pull it off because in the (wrong) example I was giving, `term` was a closure in my lambda expression and to reuse the filter I would need to make it a parameter. Now my filter is an `Expression<Lambda<Record, string, bool>>` where an `Expression<Lambda<Record, bool>>` is expected. Is this still doable?

Comment: Yes and no.  Where requires an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, so your expression must be of that type.  But it's easy to make this happen.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Although I went for the `CompiledQuery`, this method as the advantage of not tying the expression to the `DataContext`. Any any case, I learnt a lot from this!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `Expression<Func<Record, bool>>` issue that others have pointed out, I suggest looking into [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). It's very good for dynamically combining lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make it an `Expression<Func<Record, bool>>`.  Otherwise it's trying to translate the actual C# method call to SQL rather than the description of it.  This is not a guarantee that *this* version will work; I'm not sure which string functions are translatable to SQL.