# Reusable LINQ query except for where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a collection of movies which have various properties (title, release year, rating, etc) that I need to search for using a LINQ query as follows:

```
public BindingList<Movie> SearchByTitle(string title)
{
    var matches = from movies in movieCollection
                  where movies.Title == title
                  select movies;
    // do some other stuff with the matches
}
```

But I don't want a separate method to search for each property since the only thing that changes between searches is the `where` section. For example `where movies.Rating == rating` or `where movies.ReleaseYear == releaseYear`. How do I make the search method reusable for all different kinds of searches by passing in some sort of `Expression` or `Func` as the `where` section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I make the search method reusable for all different kinds of searches by passing in some sort of Expression or Func as the where section?

Your query really isn't *anything* other than the where clause. But you can easily make the where part configurable... just not using query expressions.

```
public BindingList<Movie> SearchByTitle(Expression<Func<Movie, bool>> predicate)
{
    var matches = movies.Where(predicate);

    // Do common stuff with the matches.
}
```

EDIT: I was assuming that `movies` was an `IQueryable<T>`, given that you were talking about `Expression`. If it's just an `IEnumerable<T>`, you want:

```
public BindingList<Movie> SearchByTitle(Func<Movie, bool> predicate)
{
    var matches = movies.Where(predicate);

    // Do common stuff with the matches.
}
```

Comment: This works nicely but I needed to use `var matches = movies.Where(predicate.Compile());`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension method (define this in a static class)

```
    public static IQueryable<T> AddSearchParameter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, bool condition, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            query = query.Where(predicate);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

So for example:

```
public BindingList<Movie> Search(string title, int? year, int? rating)
{
    var matches = movieCollection.AddSearchParameter(!string.IsNullorEmpty(title), m=>m.Title == title);
    matches = matches.AddSearchParameter(year.HasValue, m=>m.Year == year.Value);
    matches = matches.AddSearchParameter(rating.HasValue, m=>m.rating >= rating.Value);

    // do some other stuff with the matches
}
```

If you're using this against a database it will not actually execute the query until you enumerate so this will not make multiple calls to your database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [CompiledQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.compiledquery.aspx).

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952602/how-to-reuse-where-clauses-in-linq-to-sql-queries) very interesting answer on SO.

Hope it helps.