# How to create a reusable where clause for EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have recently moved from coding in Java to c# and I am still learning the various elements of c#.

To access an existing database, which I cannot redesign, I am using Entity Frameworks 6 and 'Code First from database' to generate contexts and types representing the database tables. I am using Ling-To-SQL to retrieve the data from the database which is heavily denormalized.

My current task is create a report where each section is read from various tables, which all have a relationship to one base table.

This is my working example:

```
using(var db = new PaymentContext()) 
{
    var out = from pay in db.Payment
              join typ in db.Type on new { pay.ID, pay.TypeID } equals 
                                     new { typ.ID, typ.TypeID }
              join base in db.BaseTable on 
                  new { pay.Key1, pay.Key2, pay.Key3, pay.Key4, pay.Key5 } equals 
                  new { base.Key1, base.Key2, base.Key3, base.Key4, base.Key5 }
              where 
              base.Cancelled.Equals("0") &&
              base.TimeStamp.CompareTo(startTime) > 0 &&
              base.TimeStamp.CompareTo(endTime) < 1 &&
              .
              (other conditions)
              .
              group new { pay, typ } by new { typ.PaymentType } into grp
              select new
              {
                  name = grp.Key,
                  count = grp.Count(),
                  total = grp.Sum(x => x.pay.Amount)
              };
}
```

There will be a large number of sections in the report and each section will generate a where clause which will contain the conditions shown. In some sections, the required data will be extracted from tables up to five levels below the BaseTable.

What I want to do is create a resuable where clause for each report section, to avoid a lot of duplicated code.

After a lot of searching, I tried to use the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952602/how-to-reuse-where-clauses-in-linq-to-sql-queries) , but this has been superseded in Entity Framework 6.

How do I avoid duplicating code unnecessarily?

Comment: Look at the second answer from the question you linked.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did look at that, but I was afraid that adding that adding a Where clause in LINQ would cause all the records to be extracted from the database. When I originally created this report in Java and SQL, I spent a lot of time fine tuning the SQL to reduce the creation time. As I am setting the condition on the BaseTable, but I end up with the grp record, how can I apply this at the end?

Comment: @PeterJordan You'd be far better served by using the straight LINQ syntax instead of the SQL-style. It has more methods available, and is more performant than the declarative syntax.

Comment: Well with simplified linq syntax you use now it's hard to extract where clause . If you would use full linq syntax - you can use separate method like provided in the answer BUT don't use IEnumerable like stated there - use IQueryable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try to use the extension clauses you suggested, but my generated classes do not extend the BaseTable, so I had to explicitly define the link through the navigation property. As only a small number of tables will be common in the queries, I decided to apply the filters directly to each table as required. I will define these as required.

krillgar suggested moving to straight LINQ syntax, which seems like good advice. We intend to redesign our database in the near future and this will remove some of the SQL dependency. I merged the suggested filters and full LINQ syntax to access my data.

```
// A class to hold all the possible conditions applied for the report
// Can be applied at various levels within the select
public class WhereConditions
{
    public string CancelledFlag { get; set; } = "0";  // <= default setting
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

// Class to define all the filters to be applied to any level of table
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<BaseTable> ApplyCancellationFilter(this IQueryable<BaseTable> base, WhereConditions clause)
    {
        return base.Where(bse => bse.CancelFlag.Equals(clause.CancelledFlag));
    }

    public static IQueryable<BaseTable> ApplyTimeFilter(this IQueryable<BaseTable> base, WhereConditions clause)
    {
        return base.Where(bse => bse.TimeStamp.CompareTo(clause.StartTime) > 0 &&
                                 bse.TimeStamp.CompareTo(clause.EndTime) < 1);
    }
}
```

And the query is composed as follows:

```
using (var db = new PaymentContext())
{
    IEnumerable<BaseTable> filter = db.BaseTable.ApplyCancellationFilter(clause).ApplyTimeFilter(clause);

    var result = db.Payment.
                Join(
                    filter,
                    pay => new { pay.Key1, pay.Key2, pay.Key3, pay.Key4, pay.Key5 },
                    bse => new { bse.Key1, bse.Key2, bse.Key3, bse.Key4, bse.Key5 },
                    (pay, bse) => new { Payment = pay, BaseTable = bse }).
                Join(
                    db.Type,
                    pay => new { pay.Payment.TypeKey1, pay.Payment.TypeKey2 },
                    typ => new { typ.TypeKey1, typ.TypeKey2 },
                    (pay, typ) => new { name = typ.Description, amount = pay.Amount }).
                GroupBy(x => x.name).
                Select(y => new { name = y.Key, 
                                  count = y.Count(), 
                                  amount = y.Sum(z => z.amount)});
}
```

And then to finally execute composed query.

```
var reportDetail = result.ToArray(); // <= Access database here
```

As this query is the simplest I will have to apply, future queries will become much more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

The nice thing about LINQ is that methods like `Where()` return an `IEnumerable<T>` that you can feed into the next method.

You could refactor the `where` clauses into [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) akin to:

```
public static class PaymentQueryExtensions {

    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyNotCancelledFilter(
        this IQueryable<T> payments) 
        where T : BaseTable {

        // no explicit 'join' needed to access properties of base class in EF Model
        return payments.Where(p => p.Cancelled.Equals("0"));
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyTimeFilter(
        this IQueryable<T> payments, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime) 
        where T: BaseTable {

        return payments.Where(p => p.TimeStamp.CompareTo(startTime) > 0 
                                && p.TimeStamp.CompareTo(endTime) < 1);
    }

    public static IGrouping<Typ, T> GroupByType(
         this IQueryable<T> payments) 
         where T: BaseTable {

        // assuming the relationship Payment -> Typ has been set up with a backlink property Payment.Typ
        // e.g. for EF fluent API: 
        //  ModelBuilder.Entity<Typ>().HasMany(t => t.Payment).WithRequired(p => p.Typ);
        return payments.GroupBy(p => p.Typ);
    }
}
```

And then compose your queries using these building blocks:

```
IEnumerable<Payment> payments = db.Payment
    .ApplyNotCancelledFilter()
    .ApplyTimeFilter(startTime, endTime);

if (renderSectionOne) {
    payments = payments.ApplySectionOneFilter();
}

var paymentsByType = payments.GroupByType();

var result = paymentsByType.Select(new
          {
              name = grp.Key,
              count = grp.Count(),
              total = grp.Sum(x => x.pay.Amount)
          }
);
```

Now that you have composed the query, execute it by enumerating. No DB access has happened until now.

```
var output = result.ToArray(); // <- DB access happens here
```

**Edit** After the suggestion of Ivan, I looked at our codebase. As he mentioned, the Extension methods should work on `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`. Just take care that you only use expressions that can be translated to SQL, i.e. do not call any custom code like an overriden `ToString()` method.

**Edit 2** If `Payment` and other model classes inherit `BaseTable`, the filter methods can be written as [generic methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) that accept any child type of `BaseTable`. Also added example for grouping method.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is not good choice for EF because it moves query evaluation to be in memory (after retrieving the whole table(s) unfiltered). The solution should definitely be based on `IQueryable<T>`, but there are implications of using custom methods inside expression tree (read - doesn't work, no supported). So while this could have been a good LINQ to Objects solution, it's not applicable for LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I will look into this.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider. I like this solution. Can you expand what the `GroupByPaymentType()` method does. This example is only one of many. The `BaseTable` will always be used, but the `Payment` table will be replaced with other linked tables. I need to apply the filter to the `BaseTable`. you have given me something to try out. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a navigation property `Payment.Typ` in your EF model?

Comment: I do not understand your question. There is a foreign key relationship between `Payment` and `Type`. I want the `Type` to access the Type name. My EF model is generated from 'Code First from a Database'. All I have are classes with collections where they are linked. My `Type` class has an `ICollection` entry to `Payment`. Is that what you call a 'navigation property'?

Comment: Yes, this collection that represents a foreign key relationship is what I meant by "navigation property". I expanded my answer to show how you could group by this property.