# Reuse a function on a specific property in any LINQ to SQL expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, ef-core-2.0

I have the following code:

```
var dbContacts = dbContacts.Where(k => k.Name != null && k.Name.ToLower().IndexOf(model.name.ToLower()) > -1);
```

which is abvoisly too long, i'm trying to achieve the following without having to repeat that function on multiple properties:

```
var dbContacts = dbContacts.Where(k => contains(k.Name,model.name));

// or

var dbContacts = dbContacts.Where(k => k.Name.ContainsIgnoreCase(model.name));
```

I checked out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952602/how-to-reuse-where-clauses-in-linq-to-sql-queries), all answers are using `Expression` where it is reusing the whole expression instead a specific function in that expression on a specific property.

However, what I tried so far (and getting LINQ expression could not be translated):

```
// defining a delegate Func

Func<string, string, bool> contains = (string str, string value) =>
{
   return str != null && str.ToLower().IndexOf(value.ToLower()) > -1;
};

// using an extension
public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string str, string value)
{
    return str.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;
}
```

I would like to reuse that function on a specific property in any LINQ to SQL expression.

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, you don't need the null check because the statement is translated into SQL. The second predicate ignores not-null strings in SQL. Secondly, you probably don't need the `ToLower` calls (that kill performance) either because the database collation is used, which in most cases is case insensitive. That leaves a short predicate that may not be worth the effort generalizing. If you still want that, there are plenty examples on the net how to do that.

Comment: Replace `Func<T, bool>` with `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman i qouted that in my question that using an `Expression` will be reusing the whole expression instead a specific function in that expression on a specific property.

Comment: EF Core can only translate expressions, or calls to known functions. It can't do anything with a `Func<T,bool>` it doesn't recognise. Your `contains` lambda has no chance of being converted to sql.

Comment: I meant to say "The second predicate ignores null strings in SQL".

Comment: @GertArnold got you. However, it's an example for a long line of code... to state my point. so that function has to be repeated in several conditions. and it doesn't seem right having to write the code several times.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood, you are trying to create a delegate function to be used as a filter in Linq queries. so at the end you need to use the delegate `Func<string, string, bool>` that you've created like this :

```
var dbContacts = dbContacts.Where(k => contains(k.Name,model.name));
```

this won't work because `Where` accepts `Func<T, bool>` so you need to do something like this :

```
Func<EntityModelClass, bool> contains = (EntityModelClass entity) =>
{
    return entity.Name != null && entity.Name.ToLower().IndexOf(entity.Model.ToLower()) > -1;
};
```

where `EntityModelClass` is the `dbContacts` entity.

then you can do this :

```
var dbContacts = dbContacts.Where(contains);
```

However, your function could be better if you do this :

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(k.Name) && k.Name.IndexOf(model.name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1
```

**UPDATE :**

From what I understood in your comments, you're probably looking for a reflection solution, where you just pass the property name and the model.

here is an example :

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereContains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string propertyName, string model)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName)); }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model)); }

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var property = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

            if (property == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(property));
            }

            var value = property.GetValue(item, null)?.ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.IndexOf(model, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then your usage would be like this :

```
var contacts = dbContacts.WhereContains("Name", model.name);
```

I hope this is what are you looking for.

Comment: That will leave me to define the entity class which is my problem in the beginning.

Comment: the main concern is reusing the function on a specific property instead of reusing the whole expression on the a static entity

Comment: @AliKleit so you have multiple entities that have the same property `Name` ? which you want to automate so you can only pass `model.name` to it ? is that right ?

Comment: Actually no, let's say for any entity with a string datatype. so it can be reused on that datatype...